# Потерял все локальные изменения после git soft reset

Tags: git, source-tree

после софт ресета в Source Tree потерял все локальные изменения, что делать?

Comment: ``git reset HEAD`` не помогает?

Comment: git reflog показал sha-1 искомого коммита, однако от git reset -- hard sha-1 эффекта не видно...

Comment: `git show sha-1` выдает потеряшку?